# Utilise more cores for ArcPy script

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, multithreading

Trying to optimise a script that I’ve made up to run a simple process of converting a cadastre (polygon) in a file geodatabase to a line feature class and then run some further processing on it. It’s been running for almost 96 hours now and is still on the first line to feature class step of the script. There’s around 3.4 million polygons. Unfortunately this tool doesn’t utilise parallel processing out of the box so it’s not the fastest.

I’ve seen people mention the use of multiprocessing however I cant seem to understand it. The line of code it’s stuck on is as follows

```
arcpy.management.FeatureToLine(NSW, NSW_Boundary, “”, “NO_ATTRIBUTES”)
```

I haven’t been game enough to stop it just in case it’s close to being done but I will if I can find a concrete (or as close to it) alternative method.

It’s running from a local disk (NVMe SSD) so that can be the bottleneck. I’ve considered splitting the feature class into multiple smaller ones but I’m not sure if that helps.

Computer specs
5900X 12 core cpu
64GB Ram
2tb nvme ssd

Comment: You do not say what format your data is in, if a shapefile have you added a spatial index?

Comment: @Hornbydd Sorry its in a file geodatabase. I haven't tried an index on it however. Would that make a considerable difference?

Comment: Since all features have to be processed anyway, i don't think that adding an index would help a lot. And AFAIK a featureclass in an FGDB has a spatial index by default. I don't have an answer, except that maybe the 3rd parameter should be `None` rather than `""`. And you should have straight quotes, but maybe that's a copy/paste issue?

Comment: "I've considered splitting the feature class"-- that would be the first step when adding your own multiprocessing.  Chunk it up into multiple parts, run feature to line on each chunk from multiple simultaneous processes, then merge the results at the end.

Comment: @Berend I think the quotes are just the pasting being funky, but i will try it None instead.

Comment: @mikewatt Thanks for the reply. I'll give that a go. I found a write up ESRI had done on multiprocessing of multiple datasets so will start there. For anyone wanting this article you can find it here [link]https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-desktop/analytics/multiprocessing-with-arcgis-approaches-and-considerations-part-1/[/link]

Comment: Something bad has happened. There is no way such a small dataset would run that long.  I suspect a peculiar invalid geometry.  There's little reason to multithread that task, because it is so I/O-bound.